# How to authenticate httpURLConnection, send request and get response

Tags: java, android, web-services, authentication, httpurlconnection

I have troubles with authentication httpURLConnection. I have a URL for POST request, but  i need to authenticate like user to get a response from server. I tried to do it with basic authentication, but it didn't work for me. Anyway i got the responseCode: 401 - unauthorized.

Do you know any other way to authenticate with httpURLConnection ? What am i doing wrong ?

This is my code:

```js
Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
  Override
  public void run() {
    try {

      Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          Log.d(TAG, " ----------------- =========== >>>> ПАРОЛЬ");
          return new PasswordAuthentication("login", "password".toCharArray());
        }
      });


      URL url = new URL("https://sscale.dk/ro/service2.asmx/stackdata");
      String urlParameters = "ix=123";

      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      String userCredentials = "login:password";
      final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
      con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

      // Send post request
      con.setRequestMethod("POST");
      con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + urlParameters.getBytes().length);
      con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
      con.setUseCaches(false);
      con.setDoInput(true);
      con.setDoOutput(true);
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
      wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
      wr.flush();
      wr.close();

      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
      System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

      while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
      } in .close();

      String result = response.toString();


      Log.d(TAG, " -----------> Мы в интернете: " + result);


    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};
networkThread.start();
```

This is my **LOGCAT**:

```
System.out: Sending 'POST' request to URL : [https://sscale.dk/ro/service2.asmx/stackdata]

System.out: Post parameters : ix=123

System.out: Response Code : 401

System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://sscale.dk/ro/service2.asmx/stackdata

System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)

System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)

System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)

System.err:     at net.caustix.redoctoberwoodapp.LoginActivity$1.run(LoginActivity.java:112)
```

I SOLVED IT ! The answer is that I get access to the wrong API page. I found the right page, login with the post params 'username' and 'password' and it worked !

Comment: https://sscale.dk/ro/service2.asmx/stackdata your link error !!!. Plz, check it !

Comment: This is API page of Web Service I am trying to access: https://sscale.dk/ro/service2.asmx

Comment: I am trying to access. It not show API of page.

Comment: API for 'stackdata' method: https://sscale.dk/ro/service2.asmx?page=op&op=stackdata&bnd=sScaleService2Soap&tab=msg

Comment: You are keeping a dog and barking yourself. *Either* use the `Authenticator` *or* the `Authorization: Basic ...` header. Not both at the same time.

Comment: I tried to comment one of the Authenticator or the Authorization: Basic and got the same result. "This web service does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1" - may it cause my problem with basic authorization ?

Comment: No, it means something else entirely. Your authorization *succeeded*, then you got an error further into the system.